# Align Select box and images

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a select box and 3 images.

I want to make this:

[image: want this]

I have this:

[image: have this]

So basically I am having trouble aligning the 3 images at the same height as the select box. I have tried several things and have no clue why it does not work.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
#lang_social {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #3CC;
  display: table;
}
#language select {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3FF;
  border-color: #3FF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  ;
}
#twitter_conn img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
#fb_conn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#linkedin_conn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang_social">
  <div id="language">
    <select>
      <option value="swe">SWEDISH</option>
      <option value="eng">ENGLISH</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="twitter_conn">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'">
  </div>
  <div id="fb_conn">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'">
  </div>
  <div id="linked_conn">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.placehold.it/32'">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The general layout

To simplify things, let's create two separate divs that are each given 50% width on one line.

They can be marked up like this:

```
<div id="lang_social">
    <div id="language"><!-- Select goes here --></div>
    <div id="social"><!-- Icons go here --></div>
</div>
```

and positioned like this, each child div is given 50% width and will line up next to the other:

```
#lang_social > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

We now have two divs on one line:

[image: Our sections]

### Right align the icons

We want the social icons to be aligned from the right, that's easy now:

```
#social {
  text-align: right;  
}
```

Apply the colours and we get the finished result:

[image: Completed]

If you want, we can end the answer here, have a snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lang_social {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3CC;
  line-height: 60px; 
  /*This Line height is the same as the height and will vertically center a single line*/
  min-width: 340px;
}
#lang_social > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;/*Important to align in the middle*/
}
#social {
  text-align: right;
}
#language select {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3FF;
  border-color: #3FF;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang_social">
  <div id="language">
    <select>
      <option value="swe">SWEDISH</option>
      <option value="eng">ENGLISH</option>
    </select>
  </div><div id="social">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/FF0000" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/FF9900" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/32/FF99CC" />
  </div>
</div>
```

or we can go a little further below.

**Note:**

- Each inline elements closing tag has no whitespace between it and the next inline elements *opening* tag, [this prevents the gaps between inline elements.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) Example:

  ```
  <div id="language">
      Contents
  </div><div id="social">
      Contents
  </div>
  ```
- [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) incorporates padding and borders into the width and height.

---

#### Hover states for the social icons using [CSS Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

If you want to, we can create a simple image hover state for each social image without javascript.

Instead of using `<img>`, we can use `<a>`, like so:

```
<div id="social">
  <a class="icon facebook"></a>
  <a class="icon twitter"></a>
  <a class="icon linked"></a>
</div>
```

This allows us to create the normal and hover state with a [CSS sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). We can apply the background to the `icon` class:

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eIYU.png);
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

The background image looks like this:

[image: Background sprite]

Each coloured section should be changed with the social logo on a transparent background.

the top row of colours is used for the unhovered icon state. The bottom row is used for the hovered state.

- Red = Facebook icon
- Orange = Twitter icon
- Pink = LinkedIn icon

Each icon section is 32px x 32px and each icon is positioned with [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```
.facebook {
  background-position: 0 0; /*x-axis | y-axis*/
}
.twitter {
  background-position: -32px 0;
}
.linked {
  background-position: -64px 0;
}
```

On hover, the `background-position` is changed to show a hover state:

```
.facebook:hover {
 background-position: 0 -32px;
}
.twitter:hover {
 background-position: -32px -32px;
}
.linked:hover {
 background-position: -64px -32px;
}
```

## Completed example

**Note:**

- Each inline elements closing tag has no whitespace between it and the next inline elements *opening* tag, [this prevents the gaps between inline elements.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
- [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) incorporates padding and borders into the width and height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lang_social {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3CC;
  line-height: 60px;
  /*This Line height is the same as the height and will vertically center a single line*/
  min-width: 340px;
}
#lang_social > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#social {
  text-align: right;
}
#language select {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3FF;
  border-color: #3FF;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eIYU.png);
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  transition: background-position .3s
}
.facebook {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.twitter {
  background-position: -32px 0;
}
.linked {
  background-position: -64px 0;
}
.facebook:hover {
  background-position: 0 -32px;
}
.twitter:hover {
  background-position: -32px -32px;
}
.linked:hover {
  background-position: -64px -32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang_social">
  <div id="language">
    <select>
      <option value="swe">SWEDISH</option>
      <option value="eng">ENGLISH</option>
    </select>
  </div><div id="social">
    <a class="icon facebook"></a><a class="icon twitter"></a><a class="icon linked"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best explanation ever. Thank you so much for the time spent :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see your icons so i have used my own. you can substitute. I made your ids into classes and gave the lang_social an overall attr of vertical-align:middle to affect everything. I also floated the language left. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb5kdo32/1/)

```css
#lang_social {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #3CC;
    display: table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.language select {
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #3FF;
    border-color: #3FF;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.twitter_conn {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width:30px;
    float:right;
}
.fb_conn {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    float:right;
}
.linkedin_conn {
    width:30px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
img {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang_social">
    <div class="language">
        <select>
            <option value="swe">SWEDISH</option>
            <option value="eng">ENGLISH</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="linkedin_conn">
        <img src="http://www.teratology.org/images/linkedin.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.teratology.org/images/linkedin.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.teratology.org/images/linkedin.png">
    </div>
    
    <div class="fb_conn">
        <img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/fb3.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/fb3.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/fb3.png'">
    </div>
        <div class="twitter_conn">
        <img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/twitter3.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/twitter3.png" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/twitter3.png'">
    </div>
    
</div>
```